# Once set up, how are NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate protocol methods called automatically?

Tags: swift, cocoa, protocols

I'm working through a tutorial that uses NSSpeechSynthesizer and two of its NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate protocol methods.  In my ViewController, I don't explicitly call the protocol methods so I'm curious as to what do I need to research in order to understand how these methods are called during runtime?  The delegate methods are working as expected but I'm wondering how are they being called which makes this possible?

```
import Cocoa



class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {
    //Now MainWindowController is more powerful by having its own KITT being able to delegate powerful functionality and do less work.  The delegate will do all the heavy lifting and return the results to MainWindowController instances.
    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var speakButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: NSButton!
    let speechSynth = NSSpeechSynthesizer.init(voice: NSSpeechSynthesizer.VoiceName.init(rawValue: "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Victoria"))

    var isSpeaking: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateButtons()
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Overriden Properties
    override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name? {
        return NSNib.Name("MainWindowController")
    }
    // MARK: - Overidden Methods
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        updateButtons()
        speechSynth?.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - UI methods
    @IBAction func speakIt(sender: NSButton) {
        //Get tuype-in text as a string
        let string = textField.stringValue
        if string.isEmpty {
            print("string from \(textField) is empty")
        } else {
            speechSynth?.startSpeaking(string)
            isSpeaking = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopIt(sender: NSButton) {
        speechSynth?.stopSpeaking()
    }

    func updateButtons(){
        if isSpeaking {
            speakButton.isEnabled = false
            stopButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            speakButton.isEnabled = true
            stopButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    // MARK: - NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate Methods
    //this functionality is considered more powerful and is made possible due to the speechSynthesizer.delegate = self
    //the delegate is doing the work and reporting that completed work to the MainWindowController instance
    //so kinda like the delegate is providing the signature and its up to us as the developers based on what we do with those parameters inside the function in order  for us to add our own creativity.
    func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool) {
        //by setting this variable to FALSE, it will fire off the didSet computed property which this variable has both storage and behavior.
        isSpeaking = false
    }

    // MARK: - NSWindowDelegate Methods
    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        return !isSpeaking
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS tests if your delegate implements the optional protocol methods and calls them on your delegate object if you do implement them.  This is a trick provided by the Objective-C runtime and only works on @objc protocols.

Comment: “iOS tests …” Note that this question is about a macOS-only technology. Your comment applies to macOS too.

Comment: @vacawama If I created my own custom protocol and made a class conform to it, would I need to call those methods explicitly or will the runtime do it for me?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: If you create your own custom protocol, and then create a class that takes a delegate pointer of that type, your class could conditionally call methods that might have been implemented by the class assigned to your delegate pointer.  Look the at the above link near the bottom *Optional Protocol Requirements*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `windowDidLoad` method contains this line:

```
    speechSynth?.delegate = self
```

This means the speech synthesizer object has a reference back to your `MainWindowController`, so the speech synthesizer object can send messages to your `MainWindowController`.

A simplified implementation inside `NSSpeechSynthesizer` could look something like this in Swift:

```
class NSSpeechSynthesizer: NSSoundDelegate {

    weak var delegate: NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate?

    func startSpeaking(_ string: String) {
        guard
            let audioData = audioData(for: string),
            let sound = NSSound(data: audioData)
            else { return }
        sound.delegate = self
        sound.play()
    }

    // Part of NSSoundDelegate
    func sound(_ sound: NSSound, didFinishPlaying finished: Bool) {
        // The first ? means Swift only sends the message if
        // delegate is not nil.
        // The second ? means Swift only sends the message if delegate
        // implements speechSynthesizer(_:didFinishSpeaking:).
        delegate?.speechSynthesizer?(self, didFinishSpeaking: finished)
    }

}
```

But it's actually implemented in Objective-C, where you have to be more verbose about checking whether the delegate handles the message:

```
- (void)sound:(NSSound *)sound didFinishPlaying:(BOOL)finished {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking:)]) {
        [delegate speechSynthesizer:self didFinishSpeaking:finished];
    }
}
```

Comment: You explanation helps.  I ask because I didn't explicitly invoke the behavior by saying speech.delegate.speechSynthesizer(:finishedSpeaking:) so my question is who or what is calling this delegate method for me?

Comment: @CosmicArrows, that is a callback from the `NSSpeechSynthesizer`.  You called the speech synthesizer to have it `startSpeaking` and it calls your method `didFinishSpeaking` to let you know that it is done.

Comment: The `NSSpeechSythesizer` operates asynchronously, which means it works in the background and doesn't tie your app up while it is working.  Your `didFinishSpeaking` method gets called to let you know when it finishes.